# Appending value to struct of struct in Golang returns invalid memory address

Tags: go, struct

I have a meal struct that "appends" another struct, except I want to add another struct "mealComponents".

```
type mealMain struct {
    *model.Meal
    Components []mealComponent `json:"components"`
}

type mealComponent struct {
    *model.MealComponent
}
```

Where *model.Meal is as follows

```
type Meal struct {
    ID               int64     `json:"id"`
}
```

What I want is basically for "mealMain" struct to act like "Meal" struct, so that I can assign values and somehow append mealComponent as child (or maybe this is not a good idea? I'm open to suggestions)

However when I do something like this

```
var meal mealMain
meal.ID = 1
```

It throws `runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference` at meal.ID assignment.

But if I do it like this:

```
type mealMain struct {
    MealMain *model.Meal `json:"meal_main"`
    Components []mealComponent `json:"components"`
}
```

Then assign it this way:

```
var meal mealMain
meal.mealMain.ID = 1
```

It works properly, but I have the return json even deeper like this:

```
{
    "MealModel": {
        "id": 1
    }
}
```

What I want is this:

```
{
    "id": 1
}
```

Note: I want to avoid changing the model.

Comment: Just do not embed pointer  types.

Comment: You seem to have a problem with the `mealResponse` type, why haven't you included its definition in the question?

Comment: I assume `mealResponse` is actually `mealMain` struct, correct?

Comment: @mkopriva I made a mistake when writing the question, it should have been mealMain

Comment: @RizkiHadiaturrasyid: adjusted my answer accordingly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to change the model:

```golang
    var meal = mealMain{
        Meal: &Meal{},
    }
    meal.ID = 1
```

The point is that in the following struct `*Meal` is set to `nil` if you don't initialize it.

```
type mealMain struct {
    *Meal
    Components []mealComponent `json:"components"`
}
```

I'd probably create a function to never have to worry about the correct initialization ever again:

```golang
func newMealMain() mealMain {
    return mealMain{
        Meal: &Meal{},
    }
}
```

Then your code would be:

```golang
    var meal = newMealMain()
    meal.ID = 1
```

Comment: Thank you. I ended up removing the * from Meal inside mealMain struct and it works fine. Also tried your solution and it works too. I think I need to learn more about pointers and initialization.

Comment: Oh, I'm wondering what is this assignment for? Meal: &Meal{}, because when I use it like this Meal: &model.Meal{}, it works but this model.Meal: &model.Meal{}, does not work?

Comment: If you want to pull it out you need to do `model.Meal = &model.Meal{}`. Is that what you meant?

Comment: I'm talking about this func newMealMain() mealMain {
    return mealMain{
        Meal: &Meal{},
    }
}
In my code it is like this Meal: &model.Meal{}, but if I write model.Meal: &model.Meal{} it errors.

Comment: Ah, it must be:
`Meal: &model.Meal{}`, not `model.Meal: &model.Meal{}`

Comment: The first `Meal` is the name of the field which defaults to the name of the struct (without the package name).